# How can i access a page with changed url in address bar

Tags: php

I have webpage with url for example
 https://mypage.com/profile.php?username=johnny345
I want to access the page by writing url in address bar as:
https://mypage.com/johnny345
How can i?? Using php

Comment: Depends on the webserver. If for example you use Apache HTTPd, then you should look up mod_rewrite.

Comment: What framework or CMS are you using? And if you can also put the script you are working on then it will be quite clear to track your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home /index.php